# Good tools to measure a  page’s usefulness?

Tags: analytics, content, usability, tools, user-engagement

I'd like to add a "Was this page useful?" part at the end of multiple pages for visitors to rate the page and leave feedback.

I could program this myself, store the data and make the reports that my client wants, but there must be an existing tool that I can incorporate that already does this.

Is there anybody who has had experience in using a tool for the same purpose? And what tool did you use?

Comment: Do you want people to leave your page to answer the question, or to do it within the page?

Comment: I'd prefer if they could ask their questions within the page itself, since they would still see the content they are inquiring about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>[KISSInsights](https://www.kissinsights.com/)</strike> [Qualaroo](https://qualaroo.com/) offers a widget to collect feedback from users about the page they're on. They charge <strike>$29/month</strike>$99/month.

You could alternatively use one of the many hosted feedback services, such as [SurveyMonkey,](http://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/tour/responsecollection) [Zoomerang](http://www.zoomerang.com/), [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com/), or [4Q](http://4q.iperceptions.com/).

Comment: Thank you Nick. I'll try to get my client to use KISSInsights. It looks like the exact tool I need for the Job.

Comment: @LuukBarten You're welcome! I should have mentioned that KISS lets you summarise responses by page in their reporting area. Quite handy for the use case you describe.

Comment: I'm getting: *The webpage at https://www.kissinsights.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED*. Have they vanished?

Comment: Oh it seems they may have morphed into [Qualaroo](https://qualaroo.com/) which now starts at $99/month. That seems a bit hefty for a simple 1-2 question feedback form. :-(

Comment: @SimonEast Thanks for mentioning this; I'll update the answer. SurveyMonkey is an alternative worth looking into — their plans start at €39/month: https://www.surveymonkey.com/curiosity/3-easy-ways-survey-website-visitors/